# Limpar uma div após execução da função que usa o innerHTML do javascript

Tags: javascript

Olá colegas estou aprendendo javascript e me deparei com uma dificuldade. Ao executar a função abaixo que pega as opções de um checkbox do html e exibi o valor de uma tabuada correspondente tenho o seguinte problema: ao clicar no botão ele exibi a tabuada normalmente , mas quando clico novamente ele exibi uma nova tabuada em baixo ao invés de limpar a anterior. Reparei que o operador de atribuição += influencia nessa questão. alguem sabe como posso resolver?

```
function calcular() {
  var box = window.document.getElementsByName('tabu');
  var msg = window.document.getElementById('result');

  if ( box[0].checked){  // selecione a tabuada de 2
      for(i=1;i<11;i++){
          var n = 2;
          var r = n * i;
          msg.innerHTML += `${n} x ${i} = ${r} <br/>` 
          }

  }else if (box[1].checked){   // selecione a tabuada de 3
    for(i=1;i<11;i++){  
    var n = 3;
    var r = n * i;
    msg.innerHTML += `${n} x ${i} = ${r} <br/>`
  }

  }

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode simplesmente limpar o innerHTML do elemento na própria função, antes do loop começar, atribuindo ele para vazio.

```
msg.innerHTML = ''
```

Desta forma sempre que a função for ativada no clique, ele irá limpar o elemento.

Espero que ajude!

Comment: obrigado meu amigo funcionou